# Cannot use jinja2 PackageLoader on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm trying to use the PackageLoader jinja2 provides but I cannot get it to work.

In my `app.yaml` I have the required libraries declared:

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: setuptools
  version: latest
```

The smallest example I could create:

```
import webapp2, sys
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
sys.path += ['lib/somepackage']

class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('common'))
        self.response.write(env.get_template('test.html').render())

routes = [(r"/", Test)]
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes, debug=True)
```

The package `common` exists in the directory `lib/somepackage` and has a package `templates` which contains a file `test.html`. The html file only contains the text 'test'.

When the `PackageLoader` is constructed it's `provider` is always a `NullProvider` when in Google App Engine. When I manually request a provider I get a `DefaultProvider` so obviously something is wrong here.

To request a provider I ensure `lib/somepackage` is in the `sys.path` by going to that dir, then:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> provider = pkg_resources.get_provider('common')
>>> provider
<pkg_resources.DefaultProvider instance at 0x8490b2c>
```

When this fails in Google App Engine, this is the relevant part of the traceback:

```
  File "/<>/test/main.py", line 7, in get
    self.response.write(env.get_template('test.html').render())
  File "/<>/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 719, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/<>/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 693, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/<>/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/<>/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/loaders.py", line 226, in get_source
    if not self.provider.has_resource(p):
  File "/<>/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 1170, in has_resource
    return self._has(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
  File "/<>/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 1218, in _has
    "Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type"
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
```

When I use a `FileSystemLoader` instead it works, however this won't work in a zip I guess:

```
import common.templates
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(common.templates.__path__))
```

I have seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809304/jinja2-packageloader-on-google-app-engine) but this isn't the problem.

**Update:**

I just tested the example in the 1.7.6 SDK and this works, however I'd love to see this working on a older SDK (or the old_dev_appserver).

Comment: I havent had a good look at your question but jinja2 is used in boilerplate, might help https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate

Comment: @peterretief I took a look at the `gae-boilerplate` project but couldn't find any usage of `PackageLoader`. But thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The problem, I think, was with `pkg_resources`.

Some of the `os` related functionality isn't implemented in GAE but either jinja2 or Google provided a workaround it seems.

These links illustrate the issue:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=60

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/issues/143

[Jinja2 PackageLoader on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809304/jinja2-packageloader-on-google-app-engine#)

https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/73/pkg_resources-fails-on-google-app-engine

I've used

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))
```

as boilerplate to get the templates from the "`template`" directory in the same directory as the file that is setting the definition. But the question is about files zipped as `eggs` and using `PackageLoader`

*Is there an `__init__.py` file inside the package?* You said it worked on 1.7.6, though.

Comment: Looking at the various links it seems this issue has been fixed in 1.2.1. However I experienced this issue on 1.7.5 which shouldn't have this issue. Did you get it working on 1.7.5?

Comment: To answer your question, yes there is an `__init__.py` in `common` and in `common.templates`. ;-)